# Mongoid performance measuring

Tags: ruby, mongodb, rspec, sinatra, mongoid

I'm building a web app using Mongoid, Sinatra and Rspec for testing.

What kind of technique or gem can be used with this stack to measure performance of queries?

Comment: Maybe New Relic MongoDB Instrumentation?: http://blog.newrelic.com/2010/07/01/redis-resque-couchdb-and-more-custom-instrumentation-in-rpm-part-1/